# How to build Lite app such as Twitter Lite or Facebook Lite

Tags: android-layout

l'm currently working on a application for the Android os and it's using some features so that it can only work on android 5.0+. Ans it's also huge(31.23 MB currently). I read a post from Facebook Lite developpers who where explaining the advantage of using Lite app version and how they've built their own. I want to do the same for my app. But I don't know how to create the UI rendering engine as they've explained, the app must download on a 2G network using LTS protocol the app user interface represented like a DOM object. So, the problem is how to build the user interface from the DOM? From their post, we can understand that using a WebView isn't a good approach. Help me please. Most of our customers use 2G. Any help will ne appreciated.

Comment: Can you also send me some base code if possible.

Comment: You need to show us what you’ve done so far, with examples of code defining a specific problem, what you’ve tried and what you’re trying to do. Your question will just get closed if left as it is.

Comment: I've never made a Lite app before. What I need is the guidlines. Specially on the UI generation. Any useful link please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is not as clear as it could be. But as I can understand, you need to know how to make an Android app that can parse XML data using DOM Parser isn't it ?
So, as I don't know what exactly your app is based of, I'm going to give a simple example of code. Maybe this can help you to adapt it with the logic of your project.

Suppose that you want to parse Users Data with DOM Parser in Android Studio, so you need to make an app like the exemple below:

1. Create a new Project in Android Studio and rename it **MyParserApp**

[image]

2. Swich in the Project View and locate **src/main** folder, Right Click to create a new directory and name it **assets** like thhis.

[image]

3. Then, right click on the **assets** folder and create a new **Andoid Ressource File** give it the name **myusers.xml** like this:

[image]

4. You can now open the file **myusers.xml** and code it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<users>

<user>

<name>Félix Maroy</name>

<fonction>CEO</fonction>

<city>Bukavu</city>

</user>

<user>

<name>Mbuyi Beya</name>

<fonction>Developer</fonction>

<city>Kinshasa</city>

</user>

<user>

<name>John Doe</name>

<fonction>Accountant</fonction>

<city>New York</city>

</user>

</users>
```

5. Create a **Layout Ressource File** in **src/layout** and name it **users_list.xml**, Open it and code like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="17dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fonction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="14dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/city"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/fonction"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fonction"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="14dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It'll looks like this:

[image]

6. Then Code your **activity_main.xml** in **src/layout** like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/user_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It'll looks like this:

[image]

7. And the last step is to code your **MainActivity.java** like this:

```
package com.mercipro.myparserapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try{
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = new ArrayList<>();
            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.user_list);
            InputStream istream = getAssets().open("myusers.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(istream);
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("user");
            for(int i =0;i<nList.getLength();i++){
                if(nList.item(0).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                    HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<>();
                    Element elm = (Element)nList.item(i);
                    user.put("name", getNodeValue("name",elm));
                    user.put("fonction", getNodeValue("fonction",elm));
                    user.put("city", getNodeValue("city",elm));
                    userList.add(user);
                }
            }
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, userList, R.layout.users_list,new String[]{"name","fonction","city"}, new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.fonction, R.id.city});
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    protected String getNodeValue(String tag, Element element) {
        NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName(tag);
        Node node = nodeList.item(0);
        if(node!=null){
            if(node.hasChildNodes()){
                Node child = node.getFirstChild();
                while (child!=null){
                    if(child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE){
                        return  child.getNodeValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

8. Now Run your app, the result will looks like this

[image]

Hope this will give you an idea on How to Parse XML using DOM Parser in Android Studio so that you can build Lite applications as you read somewhere (I never code a Lite app).

Comment: Thank you a lot. I'll try to customize your answer so that it can generate complexe UI/UX design.